# Not able to disable legend title / enable legend title as required while expoting Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, highcharts

I'm using "highcharts": "^6.1.2", I have modified legend title like this

```
legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    align: 'left',                      
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    margin:35,
    x: 90,
    y:-25,
    itemDistance: 50,
    symbolHeight : 17,
    symbolWidth : 17,
    itemStyle : {
        "fontFamily": "'Raleway', sans-serif !important",
        "fontSize"  : "14px !important",
    },
    title : {
        text : "Filter by :",
        style : {
            "fontFamily": "'Raleway', sans-serif !important",
            "fontSize" : "1rem !important",
            "color" : "#5d737e !important", 
            "fontWeight": "500 !important",
        }
    }
},
```

also loaded as

```
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
        load: function(e) { 
            var title = this.legend.title;
            title.translate(-83, 27);
        },
        redraw: function(e) { 
            var title = this.legend.title;
            title.translate(-83, 27);
        },
    }
},
```

I need to download and share this graph for that I have added custom button and used the export module.

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
    chart:{
        events: {
            load: function(e) { 
                var title = this.legend.title;
                title.translate(-83, 27);
            },
            redraw: function(e) { 
                var title = this.legend.title;
                title.translate(-83, 27);
            },
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'left',                      
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        margin:35,
        x: 90,
        y:-25,
        itemDistance: 50,
        symbolHeight : 17,
        symbolWidth : 17,
        itemStyle : {
            "fontFamily": "'Raleway', sans-serif !important",
            "fontSize"  : "14px !important",
        },
        title : {
            text : "Filter by :",
            style : {
                "fontFamily": "'Raleway', sans-serif !important",
                "fontSize" : "1rem !important",
                "color" : "#5d737e !important", 
                "fontWeight": "500 !important",
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But the legend title is not displaying correctly while exporting. it is not being applied upon customized click. But working if I'm using default download option

Here is the [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Shalom1104/o2twgu93/49/)

See the legend title position

Comment: Hi @Shalom, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? By using the code that you provided everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9hb3a27g/

Comment: @ppotaczek I have added the jsfiddle link in theQuestiont.Please check and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `JSON.stringify` for the functions. You need to post the chart as `svg`:

```
$("#download").click(function() {
    var obj = {};
    ...

    obj.svg = chart.getSVG(chart.options);
    ...

});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u739oknb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#getSVG